# How do I create a Up/Down voting system like stackoverflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a site in Rails, and I want to add a vote up/down system like here in Stackoverflow.

Can anyone suggest how to do it? I do know that I'll enter each vote into the database, but I mean, how do I code the vote buttons? What will I use, can anyone help me. Ajax isn't required but it would be nice.

I was going to try to use a POST command and do something like this,

```
<form name="input" action="/grinders" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=h grinder.id %>">
<input type="hidden" name="vote" value="up">
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

But, I get an authenticity token error, and I honestly do not know how to work with the form helper.

Answer (score 5):

Have a `votes` table like so:

```
[PK] vote_id, vote_type (up/down), [FK] post_id, [FK] user_id, time [optional]
```

Also add a `score` field to your `posts` table

Then you could have the vote button access a link like: `/vote/post_id/type/`, eg: `/vote/14098/up`. This can be done with or without Ajax.

When the vote action is called, check if the user has previously voted on that post - if yes, deny it. If not, create a row with the relevant values in the `votes` table and update the `score` field in the `posts` table.

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but can't people hack something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "hack"? It doesn't matter if the user enters the URL directly. You should still verify whether or not a user is allowed to cast a vote before saving anything to the database.

Comment: Wrap that last paragraph in a transaction block and you're good to go.